# How to generate a detail report of functional coverage in Questasim?

Tags: code-coverage, modelsim, questasim, function-coverage

How to generate the detailed coverage report of functional coverage? I am using following command to simulate my code :

```
 vlog -64 -work work -vopt +notimingchecks  +cover +fcover  -f pcie_jammer.f 

 vsim -novopt -c <CODE SPECIFIC ARGS> -t ps work.tb_top work.glbl -vopt -do "set WildcardFilter None;**coverage save -onexit -directive -cvg -codeAll pcie_cov_${1}_gen${speed}_X${width}** ; add log -r /*;coverage report -file pcie_cov_${1}_gen${speed}_X${width}.txt -byfile -detail -noannotate -option -directive -cvg -details -verbose;**coverage report -directive -cvg -details -verbose**;run -all;exit" > transcript_${tname}_gen${speed}_X${width}.txt  

 vcover report -html pcie_cov_${1}_gen${speed}_X${width} -verbose
```

I am not able to see the details of the covergroup in the report.

Comment: *function* coverage is not *functional* coverage.

Comment: But in details of Function-Coverage Tag, it is also referred as Functional Coverage.

Comment: Oh, I see. The description is correct, but the tag name is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I am able to solve the above question. Please find the solution below:

To generate a detailed function coverage report:

1.First compile and simulate your code using below mentioned script :

```
vlog -work work -O0 +fcover +acc -f pcie_jammer.f 
vsim -cvgperinstance -c <ARGUMENTS> work.tb_top work.glbl -do " coverage save -onexit <Name_of_File>.ucdb; run -all;exit"
```

Save the coverage report of the simulation in a UCDB file (Refer Questa User Manual for details about UCDB file).

2.In order to get a html or text report, reload the formed ucdb file and use coverage report to form the report as follows:

```
vsim -cvgperinstance -viewcov merged.ucdb -do "coverage report -file final_report.txt -byfile -detail -noannotate -option -cvg"
```

One can also use Questa GUI to form the report.

This approach is quite useful in order to merge the functional coverage reports of multiple testcases.

Answer (score 1):

After creating .ucdb file go to console (cmd) and type the following commands:

```
vcover report -details -html result.ucdb
```

(this is for html report with details.)

```
vcover report -details result.ucdb
```

(this is for questasim.)